# Where should I ask communication engineering questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask questions on subjects given below:

1. Signals and systems
2. Control systems
3. Analog and digital communication

Also, it would be helpful if I get to know where to ask general or mental-aptitude related questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Signals and systems. That should be covered by our [dsp.se](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) stack.
- Control systems by [electronics.se](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and [drones.se](https://drones.stackexchange.com/).
- Analog and digital communication by [ham.se.](https://ham.stackexchange.com/)

For the associated field of general engineering there's our [engineering.se](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) site and our [matter modelling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) one for something more exotic (e.g. genetic algorithms in modelling that turns up in aerial design).

As to general mental aptitude, our [psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) site may offer you something, or check-out our [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) stack for a different perspective on the matter.

If you don't find quite what you're looking for in any of those, then try browsing [the rest of our sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name), there's a remarkable range of expertise to draw on.

Always remember to take the tour and read-up in the help centre about how best to approach writing an on-topic question in a way that's likely to elicit the answer most helpful to you.

Perhaps most useful of all, the search bar at the top of every site can be invaluable to save time.